# Google Calendar Trigger Not Working

Tags: ifttt

I have the Google Calendar service set up as a trigger in an applet I've created. This trigger is set up with "New event added" and as the description states I'm expecting "This Trigger fires every time a new event is added to your Google Calendar."

To test my applet, I'm manually adding an event in Google Calendar. However, after creating the event, my applet never runs.
After manually adding an event in Google Calendar, I'm waiting 15+ minutes and still, the applet never runs. I am confirming this by reviewing it's activity and nothing gets listed. No errors, just nothing. When I manually click the 'Check Now' button on the settings page of the applet, then the applet runs as expected and the activity is shown. However, it does not run automatically as expected.

I've confirmed I'm creating an event on the same calendar as that I've selected in the applet. I'm creating the event for a date/time into the future. I've confirmed the Google Calendar service in IFTTT has access to my Google account, completed oAuth, and even verified in my Google Security Checkup that IFTTT has access to my Google Calendar.
Any guesses as to what could be causing this issue?

Comment: After testing this further, on average the applet is running about an hour after the event is created.